# Is there a Shopify Hydrogen component or hook to display the shop pay installments banner?

Tags: reactjs, shopify, e-commerce, shopify-hydrogen

I can see that it is possible to add this into a theme (reference: https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/pricing-payments/installments). But I cannot find any documentation regarding showing this in a custom store using Shopify hydrogen.